# How to change <div id='<%='product'+ `${arr[i]}` %>''></div> to iterate different numbers based on collection

Tags: node.js, for-loop, ejs

I'm trying to get the   to add a number on the end based on the posts.length without creating duplicates.

```
enter code here

<h1>Home</h1>
<p> <%= startingContent %> </p>
<% let arr = []; %>
<% let i = 0; %>
<% while (i < posts.length) { %>
    <% arr.push(i); %>
    <% i++; %>
<% } %>
<% for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) { %>
    <% posts.forEach((post) => { %>
    <div id='<%='product'+ `${arr[i]}` %>'>
            <h1> <%= post.title %></h1>
            <p> <%= post.content.substring(0, 100)  + '...'; %>
                <a href='/post/<%=post._id%>'>Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
    <% } %>
```

output:

```
 <div id="product0">...</div>

 <div id="product0">...</div>

 <div id="product0">...</div>

 <div id="product0">...</div>

 <div id="product1">...</div>
```

...

...

etc...

What I trying to get:

```
   <div id="product0">...</div>

   <div id="product1">...</div>

   <div id="product2">...</div>

   <div id="product3">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
<% for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) { %>
<% posts.forEach((post) => { %>
<div id='<%='product'+ `${arr[i]}` %>'>
        <h1> <%= post.title %></h1>
        <p> <%= post.content.substring(0, 100)  + '...'; %>
            <a href='/post/<%=post._id%>'>Read More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
<% }); %>
<% } %>
```

to this

```
<% for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) { %>
<div id='<%=`product${arr[i]}` %>'>
<% posts.forEach((post) => { %>
        <h1> <%= post.title %></h1>
        <p> <%= post.content.substring(0, 100)  + '...'; %>
            <a href='/post/<%=post._id%>'>Read More</a>
        </p>

<% }); %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I get `posts.forEach()` to only output one object for each div.